# Are there systemic impediments to popular opposition candidates winning presidential elections in Russia?

Tags: russian-federation, vladimir-putin

Are there systemic impediments to popular opposition candidates winning presidential elections in Russia?

I'm not asking about pro-western candidates in particular.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a "systemic impediment"? I.e. during the most recent election campaign other candidates apparently got significantly less screen time on TV and thus had less opportunity to gain publicity - does that count?

Comment: You mean other than getting shot, poisoned or being put in prison?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/32287/does-the-opposition-figure-with-the-highest-chance-to-challenge-putin-always-end